# App crashing on Heroku Pyphon application

Tags: python, heroku

Hi could any help me with my .Py Application it is a bot for my website chat room and I'm currently having issues with it keep on crashing.

I'm new to python so I'm unsure how to correct this.

Here is the app log

```html
2016-09-28T17:33:36.856407+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python pinybot.py`
2016-09-28T17:33:40.278003+00:00 app[web.1]: --> Now checking module updates...
2016-09-28T17:33:42.778247+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting up: pip
2016-09-28T17:33:43.417702+00:00 app[web.1]: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pip in ./.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg
2016-09-28T17:33:44.167819+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting up: requests
2016-09-28T17:33:44.774642+00:00 app[web.1]: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in ./.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages
2016-09-28T17:33:45.512264+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting up: pyamf
2016-09-28T17:33:46.095476+00:00 app[web.1]: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyamf in ./.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages
2016-09-28T17:33:46.102778+00:00 app[web.1]: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): defusedxml in ./.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pyamf)
2016-09-28T17:33:46.657006+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting up: colorama
2016-09-28T17:33:47.349365+00:00 app[web.1]: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): colorama in ./.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages
2016-09-28T17:33:47.980547+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting up: beautifulsoup4
2016-09-28T17:33:48.631215+00:00 app[web.1]: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in ./.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages
2016-09-28T17:33:49.148829+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting up: wikipedia
2016-09-28T17:33:49.715791+00:00 app[web.1]: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): wikipedia in ./.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages
2016-09-28T17:33:49.719299+00:00 app[web.1]: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in ./.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from wikipedia)
2016-09-28T17:33:49.720919+00:00 app[web.1]: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0 in ./.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from wikipedia)
2016-09-28T17:33:50.311164+00:00 app[web.1]: --> Module checking complete.
2016-09-28T17:33:52.822285+00:00 app[web.1]: TERM environment variable not set.
2016-09-28T17:33:52.826437+00:00 app[web.1]: --> Now checking bot updates...
2016-09-28T17:33:54.330070+00:00 app[web.1]: --> Fetching from repository: https://github.com/TechWhizZ199/pinybot.git
2016-09-28T17:33:55.449425+00:00 app[web.1]: --> Detecting version data.
2016-09-28T17:33:56.453883+00:00 app[web.1]: --> Your version: 1.41 Repository version: 1.41
2016-09-28T17:33:56.453922+00:00 app[web.1]: You are running the latest version.
2016-09-28T17:33:58.460095+00:00 app[web.1]: TERM environment variable not set.
2016-09-28T17:33:58.461830+00:00 app[web.1]: Enter room name: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-09-28T17:33:58.461865+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "pinybot.py", line 3377, in <module>
2016-09-28T17:33:58.462585+00:00 app[web.1]:     main()
2016-09-28T17:33:58.462617+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "pinybot.py", line 3290, in main
2016-09-28T17:33:58.463169+00:00 app[web.1]:     room_name = raw_input('Enter room name: ')
2016-09-28T17:33:58.463231+00:00 app[web.1]: EOFError: EOF when reading a line
2016-09-28T17:33:58.573090+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-09-28T17:33:58.594752+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Here is the error

`2016-09-28T17:33:58.463231+00:00 app[web.1]: EOFError: EOF when reading a line
2016-09-28T17:33:58.573090+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-09-28T17:33:58.594752+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed`

Comment: You can't use `raw_input()` in a web app.

Comment: what would be the alternative

Comment: What do you want to do? Your code would be helpful.

Comment: This is a chat room bot that you run from the terminal at the moment the bot runs from a local machine I'm trying to get the bot to run automatically on Heruko so far I can manually run the .py file with this command `heroku run --app cghelper python bot.by` all files are in my github repo. You can see here https://github.com/sean-james/lilbot/tree/master