# Heroku EOFError for only two line python code

Tags: python, heroku, web-applications

Its my first attempt to deploy a python program to Heroku.

My python program was

```
name=input("What is your name?: ");
print("Nice to meet you", name)
```

and `https://shielded-gorge-83102.herokuapp.com/`says

```
Application error 
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

On executing logs command:

```
(intro) D:\heroku>heroku logs
    2018-12-12T13:43:55.763708+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user m.naufil1@gmail.com
    2018-12-12T13:43:55.600014+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user m.naufil1@gmail.com
    2018-12-12T13:43:55.600014+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user m.naufil1@gmail.com
    2018-12-12T13:43:55.763708+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user m.naufil1@gmail.com
    2018-12-12T13:44:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user m.naufil1@gmail.com
    2018-12-12T13:44:33.155579+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user m.naufil1@gmail.com
    2018-12-12T13:44:33.172663+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user m.naufil1@gmail.com
    2018-12-12T13:44:36.735728+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python script.py`
    2018-12-12T13:44:38.669558+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2018-12-12T13:44:38.605013+00:00 app[web.1]: What is your name?: Traceback (most recent call last):
    2018-12-12T13:44:38.605042+00:00 app[web.1]: File "script.py", line 8, in <module>
    2018-12-12T13:44:38.605143+00:00 app[web.1]: name=input("What is your name?: ");
    2018-12-12T13:44:38.605148+00:00 app[web.1]: EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    2018-12-12T13:44:38.834792+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2018-12-12T13:44:38.836807+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2018-12-12T13:44:42.997678+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python script.py`
    2018-12-12T13:44:45.507921+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2018-12-12T13:44:45.418724+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2018-12-12T13:44:45.349072+00:00 app[web.1]: What is your name?: Traceback (most recent call last):
    2018-12-12T13:44:45.357936+00:00 app[web.1]: File "script.py", line 8, in <module>
    2018-12-12T13:44:45.360501+00:00 app[web.1]: name=input("What is your name?: ");
    2018-12-12T13:44:45.360593+00:00 app[web.1]: EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    2018-12-12T13:45:01.410054+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=shielded-gorge-83102.herokuapp.com request_id=95386b8c-f2e6-4d0f-8dcb-6355cf75da60 fwd="39.50.204.180" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I read this post: [App crashing on Heroku Pyphon application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756388/app-crashing-on-heroku-pyphon-application)

and it says `you cant use input command here`. So is this because it is a web app and print command cant run on browser? Please tell me how to run this program without taking input.

So, if we need a bit HTML here, I also know working with HTML. So please help me with running this program using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still have `input`, but in a bit different way. Check out this [Send data from a textbox into Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277933/send-data-from-a-textbox-into-flask)

Then once you have a simple app follow this tutorial to get it deployed https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python

Most likely you know most of the steps already. Also not all of them are mandatory.